# templavoila switch between image field and typoscript-objectpath for same element

Tags: mapping, typo3, typoscript, templavoila

My issue is that I have to find an elegant way of mapping either an image-slider OR a simple, non-animated image to the same div-element.

I want to select a header image for each page in the page configuration. If this field stays empty, I'll set the image-slider with typoscript for the corresponding lib-element.

Is there an elegant way of accomplishing this?

Best regards! :)

Comment: Maybe its better to check with JavaScript, if there are multiple images or not. And if not, don't activate the slider.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with nested COAs and simple TypoScript conditions. Something along the (untested) lines of this:

```
10 = COA
10 {
    # COA for HTML/whatever for you image slider
    10 = COA
    10.if.isTrue.field = fieldname_of_field_with_images

    # COA for your lib element
    20 = COA
    20.if.isFalse.field = fieldname_of_field_with_images
    20.10 < lib.fallback_thing_defined_elsewhere
}
```